# Cannot read property 'next' of undefined - How to mock BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular

I am learning angular and how to write tests in Angular as well. I need some guidance about how to mock `BehaviorSubject` as I am getting this error 'Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined'.

```
This is the code for my service:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NumberService {
  public number = new BehaviorSubject<string>(undefined);
  private lastNumber = undefined;
  constructor() { }

  next (number: string) {
    if (number !== this.number) { 
      this.number.next(number);
      this.lastNumber = number; 
    }
  }
}
```

I have then subscribed the number in component:

And now my testing file

```
  const restStub = jasmine.createSpyObj('RestService', ['getDetails']);
  const NumberStub = jasmine.createSpyObj('NumberService', ['next']);

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent ],
      imports: [
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: RestService, useValue: restStub },
        { provide: NumberService, useValue: NumberStub},
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

it('should display ......', () => {
  numberStub.next('abc');
  restStub.getDeviceInfo.and.returnValue(of(SampleData()));
  createComponent();
  expect(component.deviceDetails.type).toBe('abc');
});
```

Can anyone please help about how to mock `BehaviorSubject` correctly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your implementation, I created a similar test.
For services, you can simply create their instance and use them.

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
const numberService:NumberService = new NumberService();
beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: NumberService, useValue: numberService},
  ]
})
.compileComponents();
  }));

it('should display ......', () => {
numberService.next('abc');
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
app.ngOnInit();
 expect(app.number).toBe('abc');
});
```

Comment: Of course, I have done that. It is just that in the snippet I did not add it here as the focus was on the content.